# Ocultar columnas que sumen 0 - PIVOT Dinámico SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Saludos a la comunidad.

Tengo el siguiente problema: tengo una consulta con `PIVOT` que me arroja el resultado que requiero, sin embargo me hace falta hacerlo "dinámico" o no sé cuál sea el término exacto.

Básicamente tengo esto:

```sql
select X.IdPer, X.FechaIngreso, 
        SUM(ISNULL(CAST(X.[2019-Gan.] AS INT),0)) AS '2019-Gan' , 
SUM(ISNULL(X.[2019-Goz.], 0)) AS '2019-Goz',
        SUM(ISNULL(CAST(X.[2020-Gan.] as int),0)) AS '2020-Gan' , 
SUM(ISNULL(X.[2020-Goz.],0)) AS '2020-Goz' ,
        SUM(ISNULL(cast(X.[2021-Gan.] as int),0))  AS '2021-Gan', 
SUM(ISNULL(X.[2021-Goz.],0)) AS '2021-Goz',
        SUM(ISNULL(cast(X.[2022-Gan.] as int),0)) AS '2022-Gan' , 
SUM(ISNULL(X.[2022-Goz.],0)) AS '2022-Goz' ,
        SUM(ISNULL(cast (X.[2023-Gan.] as int),0)) AS '2023-Gan', 
SUM(ISNULL(X.[2023-Goz.],0))  AS '2023-Goz'
from ( 
select *
from ( 

select IdPer,   FechaIngreso,   FechaInicio,    FechaFin, 
    CASE WHEN ANIO IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(ANIO,'-Gan.') END ANIO1,
    CASE WHEN ANIO IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(ANIO,'-Goz.') END ANIO2,
(CASE WHEN  DiasGanados=30 THEN DiasGanados ELSE ((DiasGanados/360)*30) END) DiasGanados
        ,(CASE WHEN V.PINI IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 30 END)DiasGozados
    --,v.PIni,v.PFin

from @T_Vacaciones T
LEFT JOIN PLANILLAS..vacaciones V 
ON V.id_per=T.IdPer AND V.PIni=RIGHT('000000' + CONCAT(MONTH(T.FechaInicio),year(t.FechaInicio) ),6) 
and v.PFin= RIGHT('000000' + CONCAT(right('00' + MONTH(T.FechaFin),2),year(t.FechaFin)),6) 

) a
pivot (sum(DiasGanados) for ANIO1 in ([2019-Gan.],[2020-Gan.],[2021-Gan.],[2022-Gan.],[2023-Gan.])) as pv1 
pivot (sum(DiasGozados) for ANIO2 in ([2019-Goz.],[2020-Goz.],[2021-Goz.],[2022-Goz.],[2023-Goz.])) as pv2
) X 

GROUP BY X.IdPer, X.FechaIngreso
```

El cual arroja como resultado lo siguiente:

[image: foto]

En este caso, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que esta consulta no me traiga aquellas columnas que sumen 0 (cero)? p. ej. la columna `2023-Goz`

Agradezco desde ya las respuestas o aportes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pides es **"anómalo"**, para los lenguajes de bases de datos, que se basan en ser **declarativos**.

Te voy a dar un camino, pero tendrás que trabajarlo un poco.

Un par de variables de tabla con más o menos lo que tú muestras.

```
Declare @T_Vacaciones table
                            (
                            idPer        int
                          , FechaIngreso datetime
                          , FechaInicio  datetime
                          , FechaFin     datetime
                          , Anio         int
                          , DiasGanados  int
                            );

Declare @Vacaciones table
                          (
                          idPer int
                        , pini  int
                          );

Insert into @T_Vacaciones(idPer
                        , Fechaingreso
                        , FechaINicio
                        , FechaFin
                        , Anio
                        , DiasGanados)
values
       ( 1, '20170101', '20170101', null, 2019, 30 ),
       ( 2, '20180301', '20180301', null, 2019, 30 ),
       ( 3, '20210501', '20210501', null, 2019, 30 ),
       ( 1, '20170101', '20170101', null, 2019, 125 ),
       ( 2, '20180301', '20180301', null, 2019, 312 ),
       ( 3, '20210501', '20210501', null, 2019, 84 );

Insert into @Vacaciones(idPer
                      , pini)
values
       ( 1, 30 );
--- Fin datos


;with cte as (
select X.IdPer
     , X.FechaIngreso
     , Sum(ISNULL(Cast(X.[2019-Gan.] AS INT), 0)) AS '2019-Gan'
     , Sum(ISNULL(X.[2019-Goz.], 0)) AS '2019-Goz'
     , Sum(ISNULL(Cast(X.[2020-Gan.] as int), 0)) AS '2020-Gan'
     , Sum(ISNULL(X.[2020-Goz.], 0)) AS '2020-Goz'
     , Sum(ISNULL(Cast(X.[2021-Gan.] as int), 0)) AS '2021-Gan'
     , Sum(ISNULL(X.[2021-Goz.], 0)) AS '2021-Goz'
     , Sum(ISNULL(Cast(X.[2022-Gan.] as int), 0)) AS '2022-Gan'
     , Sum(ISNULL(X.[2022-Goz.], 0)) AS '2022-Goz'
     , Sum(ISNULL(Cast(X.[2023-Gan.] as int), 0)) AS '2023-Gan'
     , Sum(ISNULL(X.[2023-Goz.], 0)) AS '2023-Goz'
       from (
              select *
                     from (
                            select t.IdPer
                                 , FechaIngreso
                                 , FechaInicio
                                 , FechaFin
                                 , CASE
                                       WHEN ANIO IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(ANIO, '-Gan.')
                                   END AS ANIO1
                                 , CASE
                                       WHEN ANIO IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(ANIO, '-Goz.')
                                   END AS ANIO2
                                 , CASE
                                       WHEN DiasGanados = 30 THEN DiasGanados
                                   ELSE
                                   (
                                   DiasGanados / 360) * 30
                                   END AS DiasGanados
                                 , CASE
                                       WHEN V.PINI IS NULL THEN NULL
                                   ELSE 30
                                   END AS DiasGozados
                            --,v.PIni,v.PFin

                                   from @T_Vacaciones AS T
                                        LEFT JOIN @Vacaciones AS v ON V.idper = T.IdPer
                          ) AS a pivot(Sum(DiasGanados) for ANIO1 in([2019-Gan.]
                                                                   , [2020-Gan.]
                                                                   , [2021-Gan.]
                                                                   , [2022-Gan.]
                                                                   , [2023-Gan.])) as pv1 
                                 pivot(Sum(DiasGozados) for ANIO2 in([2019-Goz.]
                                                                   , [2020-Goz.]
                                                                   , [2021-Goz.]
                                                                   , [2022-Goz.]
                                                                   , [2023-Goz.])) as pv2
            ) AS X
       GROUP BY X.IdPer
              , X.FechaIngreso
)
select * from cte
```

[image: Resultado]

Eso es más o menos lo mismo que muestras (los datos no importan nada).
Con esa misma estructura, y fíjate que de tú consulta, solo he variado que la he metido en una cte, porque ahora voy a recoger las columnas, realizando un Unpivot sobre los valores.

```
Declare @T_Vacaciones table
                        (
                        idPer        int
                      , FechaIngreso datetime
                      , FechaInicio  datetime
                      , FechaFin     datetime
                      , Anio         int
                      , DiasGanados  int
                        );

Declare @Vacaciones table
                      (
                      idPer int
                    , pini  int
                      );

Insert into @T_Vacaciones(idPer
                    , Fechaingreso
                    , FechaINicio
                    , FechaFin
                    , Anio
                    , DiasGanados)
values
   ( 1, '20170101', '20170101', null, 2019, 30 ),
   ( 2, '20180301', '20180301', null, 2019, 30 ),
   ( 3, '20210501', '20210501', null, 2019, 30 ),
   ( 1, '20170101', '20170101', null, 2019, 125 ),
   ( 2, '20180301', '20180301', null, 2019, 312 ),
   ( 3, '20210501', '20210501', null, 2019, 84 );

Insert into @Vacaciones(idPer
                  , pini)
values
   ( 1, 30 );
--- Fin datos

with cte
 as (select X.IdPer
          , X.FechaIngreso
          , Sum(ISNULL(Cast(X.[2019-Gan.] AS INT), 0)) AS '2019-Gan'
          , Sum(ISNULL(X.[2019-Goz.], 0)) AS '2019-Goz'
          , Sum(ISNULL(Cast(X.[2020-Gan.] as int), 0)) AS '2020-Gan'
          , Sum(ISNULL(X.[2020-Goz.], 0)) AS '2020-Goz'
          , Sum(ISNULL(Cast(X.[2021-Gan.] as int), 0)) AS '2021-Gan'
          , Sum(ISNULL(X.[2021-Goz.], 0)) AS '2021-Goz'
          , Sum(ISNULL(Cast(X.[2022-Gan.] as int), 0)) AS '2022-Gan'
          , Sum(ISNULL(X.[2022-Goz.], 0)) AS '2022-Goz'
          , Sum(ISNULL(Cast(X.[2023-Gan.] as int), 0)) AS '2023-Gan'
          , Sum(ISNULL(X.[2023-Goz.], 0)) AS '2023-Goz'
            from (
                   select *
                          from (
                                 select t.IdPer
                                      , FechaIngreso
                                      , FechaInicio
                                      , FechaFin
                                      , CASE
                                            WHEN ANIO IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(ANIO, '-Gan.')
                                        END AS ANIO1
                                      , CASE
                                            WHEN ANIO IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(ANIO, '-Goz.')
                                        END AS ANIO2
                                      , CASE
                                            WHEN DiasGanados = 30 THEN DiasGanados
                                        ELSE
                                        (
                                        DiasGanados / 360) * 30
                                        END AS DiasGanados
                                      , CASE
                                            WHEN V.PINI IS NULL THEN NULL
                                        ELSE 30
                                        END AS DiasGozados
                                 --,v.PIni,v.PFin

                                        from @T_Vacaciones AS T
                                             LEFT JOIN @Vacaciones AS v ON V.idper = T.IdPer
                               ) AS a pivot(Sum(DiasGanados) for ANIO1 in([2019-Gan.]
                                                                        , [2020-Gan.]
                                                                        , [2021-Gan.]
                                                                        , [2022-Gan.]
                                                                        , [2023-Gan.])) as pv1 pivot(Sum(DiasGozados) for ANIO2 in([2019-Goz.]
                                                                                                                                 , [2020-Goz.]
                                                                                                                                 , [2021-Goz.]
                                                                                                                                 , [2022-Goz.]
                                                                                                                                 , [2023-Goz.])) as pv2
                 ) AS X
            GROUP BY X.IdPer
                   , X.FechaIngreso)
 Select DISTINCT 
        UPV.columnas
        from cte unpivot(col1 for columnas in([2019-Gan]
                                            , [2019-GOZ]
                                            , [2020-GAN]
                                            , [2020-GOZ]
                                            , [2021-GAN]
                                            , [2021-GOZ]
                                            , [2022-GAN]
                                            , [2022-GOZ]
                                            , [2023-GAN]
                                            , [2023-GOZ])) AS UPV
        WHERE UPV.col1 > 0;
```

[image: Resultado]

Por tanto esas son las dos columnas que necesitas. Además de idPer y Fecha.

Para no repetir siempre el mismo código usando variables de tabla en adelante solo pondré .... y lo que cambie.

```
Declare @var nvarchar(max)=N'';

....),
    Distintos as (
     Select  Distinct 
            UPV.columnas
            from cte unpivot(col1 for columnas in([2019-Gan]
                                                , [2019-GOZ]
                                                , [2020-GAN]
                                                , [2020-GOZ]
                                                , [2021-GAN]
                                                , [2021-GOZ]
                                                , [2022-GAN]
                                                , [2022-GOZ]
                                                , [2023-GAN]
                                                , [2023-GOZ])) AS UPV
            WHERE UPV.col1 > 0
 ) Select @var = Concat(@var, QuoteName( distintos.columnas),', ') from Distintos
```

Y en @var ahora tengo los nombres de las columnas que tienen algún valor. Le añado los que ya sabía que necesitaba.

```
select @var = 'idPer, FechaIngreso, '+@var ;

select @var
```

[image: Resultado5]

A partir de aquí, ya solo me resta reconvertir la consulta en un pivot dinámico.

[Pivot dinámico](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/14/pivot-dinamico-como-hacerlo-y-entenderlo/)

[Unpivot](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2021/01/10/unpivot-cambiar-columnas-a-filas/)